# How can I get packets of data from a HEX string in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a hexadecimal string from a PLC. The data comes from 3 sensors and the string is 12 characters long. For example 00150C950137 so the data for the sensors is 0015, 0C95 and 0137.

I converted the first 4 easily but it gives me an error when I try to convert the 2nd and 3rd. This is what I'm using:

```
ResData.Text = strRes & ": " & strRes.Substring(0, 4) & " - " & strRes.Substring(4, 4) & " - " & strRes.Substring(8, 4)

Dim lbl1 = strRes.Substring(0, 4).ToString
lbl1 = Convert.ToByte(lbl1, 16)

Dim lbl2 = strRes.Substring(4, 4).ToString
lbl2 = Convert.ToByte(lbl2, 16)

Dim prg1 = strRes.Substring(8, 4).ToString
prg1 = Convert.ToByte(prg1, 16)

Label1.Text = "Plug Catcher: " & lbl1 & " psi"
Label3.Text = "Manifold: " & lbl2 & " psi"
MyVerticalProgessBar1.Value = prg1
```

The first line is there to show the whole string and also the 3 different groups of data and it works fine in HEX.

The lbl1 convertion also works. For example 0015 gives me 21. The problem comes with the lbl2 and the prg1. It says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value was either too large or too small for an
>   unsigned byte.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Convert.ToByte()` will only handle bytes (ie. up to FF). Your first example happens to work because it is less than FF (ie. less than the 255 maximum). To convert up to FFFF you could use `ToUInt32()`

Comment: Are you working with vb.net or vba? What's the value of strRes when this starts. Also, those ".ToString" commands aren't doing anything since substring spits out a string.

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory bytes can only be 0-255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert it to a four digit hexadecimal number into a single `Byte`.  Each digit in a hexadecimal number has a range of 0 to F (0 to 15).  So a two decimal hexadecimal number can range from 0 to FF (0 to 255).  The `Byte` type only allows for values ranging from 0 to 255.  In other words, each two-digit pair in a hexadecimal string represents one byte.  So, in your example, the number 00150C950137 represents six bytes:

```
 00 15 0C 95 01 37
```

When you are converting from a hexadecimal string to a `Byte`, only values up to FF will be allowed.  Anything larger than FF will throw an `OverflowException`.  If you need to get the numeric value of a four digit hexadecimal string, that's not a `Byte`, that's a 16-bit integer (a byte is 8 bits).  In VB.NET, the types for 16-bit integers are called `Short` and `UShort`.  So, for instance:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToByte("00FF", 16))   ' Writes 255
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt16("00FF", 16)) ' Writes 255
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt16("0100", 16)) ' Writes 256
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToByte("0100", 16))   ' Throws an OverflowException
```

So, if you need all four digits, you probably want it as an unsigned 16-bit `UShort`, like this:

```
Dim val1 As UShort = Convert.ToUInt16(strRes.Substring(0, 4), 16)
Dim val2 As UShort = Convert.ToUInt16(strRes.Substring(4, 4), 16)
Dim val3 As UShort = Convert.ToUInt16(strRes.Substring(8, 4), 16)
```

When reading multiple bytes, however, you may very well need to care about the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte-order) of both your current platform and the platform that is sending the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven. Worked perfectly. It's been too many decades since I worked with this. I actually used `Dim val1 As UShort = Convert.ToUInt16(strRes.Substring(0, 4), 16)`. Does that makes sense? It did worked.

Comment: Oops.  I see I had that wrong in my example.  Yes, that makes sense.  As long as you do that for all three integers, not just the first one, and as long as you expect it to be an unsigned integer rather than a signed one, that will work well.